# how to excute a c excecutable in java servlet (Tomcat)

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat7

problem is not able a create files i.e which are to be created by c executable

What i have done is , wrote a applet which communicates with java servlet then this servlet calls a c exceutable with the help of exec(),which has to create a txt files
but the issue is not able to create files when i am running the servlet
but able to create when i run independently

Comment: User rights. The servlet is most likely run as "tomcat" or something alike. When you "run independently" it is your user that's trying to create a file.

Comment: so is it issue with permissions ?
if it is how to resolve ?